# How to use Scala reduceLeft on case classes?

Tags: scala

I understand how to use reduceLeft on simple lists of integers but attempts to use if on case class objects fail.

Assume I have:

```
  case class LogMsg(time:Int, cat:String, msg:String)
  val cList = List(LogMsg(1,"a", "bla"), LogMsg(2,"a", "bla"), LogMsg(4,"b", "bla"))
```

and I want to find the largest difference in time between LogMsgs.
I want to do something like:

```
cList.reduceLeft((a,b) => (b.time - a.time)
```

which of course doesn't work.
The first iteration of reduceLeft compares the first two elements, which are both of type LogMsg.  After that it compares the next element (LogMsg) with the result of the first iteration (Int).

Do I just have the syntax wrong or should I be doing this another way?

Comment: Your "-" should return a LogMsg, not an integer. Override the "-" operator in your object instead of doing it on the time object.

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
(cList, cList.tail).zipped.map((a, b) => b.time - a.time).max
```

You'll need to check beforehand that `cList` has at least 2 elements.

`reduceLeft` can't be used to return the largest difference, because it always returns the type of the List you're reducing, i.e. `LogMsg` in this case, and you're asking for an `Int`.

Answer (score 6):

My try:

```
cList.sliding(2).map(t => t(1).time - t(0).time).max
```

Another one that came into my mind: since `LogMsg` is a case class, we can take advantage of pattern matching:

```
cList.sliding(2).collect{
  case List(LogMsg(a, _, _), LogMsg(b, _, _)) => b - a}.
max
```

Comment: I like this, "sliding" seems more intuitive than "zipped.map" (which may just be another way of saying I don't fully grok "zipped.map"!)

Comment: @BrianTarbox What if I rewrote the zipped.map this way? `(cList, xcList.tail).zipped.map(t => t._2.time - t._1.time).max`. `cList.sliding(2)` is *almost* the same as `(cList, cList.tail).zipped`, except the former uses a 2-element Vector, while the latter uses a 2-tuple.

Comment: @Brian I sympathise, since the documentation for `Zipped` is sparse and confusing. A good place to start is in the `Tuple2` docs if you expand the `zipped` method, and check the link to the `Zipped` class. @Dan I think you mean `zip` rather than `zipped` in your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand you to use `foldLeft` which is a `reduceLeft` enabling you to initialize the results.

```
val head::tail = cList
tail.foldLeft((head.time, 0)) ((a,b) => (b.time, math.max(a._2,b.time-a._1)))._2
```

Comment: This seems to give the wrong answer..."3" in this case while the correct answer is "2".

Comment: So it seems I didn't understand what you wanted. I will modify or delete my answer according to my research.

Comment: My appologies, I see I was not clear in my question.  I was looking for the largest difference in the time value for adjacent items in the list.  Since the time values in the list were 1,2,4 the largest diff would be 4-2=2, as opposed to largest diff anywhere (4-1=3).

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to match your question (I actually didn't read it well). I now gives a 2.